# File already exists starting ClickOnce

Tags: c#, clickonce, manifest

In my application manifest (`app.manifest`) I have a dependency to a manifest file (`test.manifest`).

When I publish my project and attempt to start it, I get an error saying:

> The file '...\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\ZXCRGKX9.CVP\XNY9KJEX.XCM\test.manifest' already exists.

I read somewhere that a solution would be to change the properties of my test.manifest file to

```
'Build Action : None (prev Content)'
```

and

```
'Copy : Do not Copy (prev Always)'
```

but this only resulted in another error:

> Could not find file ....\File_Specified_In_TestManifest.dll

This DLL should not be accessed yet!

What could be the issue and how do I how to fix it?

P.S.: It is worth mentioning that the files specified in `test.manifest` are not present in the folder, but as these components are actually not accessed I believe the application should run anyway.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your temp folder ?

Comment: yes, tried it just now. Still says it already exists. Strange however, the folder it refers to doesn't even exist... :s

Comment: That folder may be hidden in Windows Explorer. Try to find and click the checkbox "Show hidden files, folder, and drives". See e.g. "How To Show Hidden Files and Folders in Windows 7", http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/show-hidden-files-windows-7.htm

Comment: Or on Super User, *[How do you show hidden system folders in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/101999/how-do-you-show-hidden-system-folders-in-windows-7)*.

Comment: I entered the path directly, so it should have worked though. I believe it might already have been deleted by the application.